# Logic: Knights and Liars

Tags: logic

Question from the Russian Olympiad. (Translated with Google Translate, with a translation fix.):

> In a circle there are $181$ people, each of whom is either a knight or a liar (liars always lie, and knights always tell the truth). Each of those standing said: “Two places away from me there is at least one liar.” 
>   Find the smallest possible number of liars among these $181$ people.

My solution:

I first estimated that there were $5$ people then the minimum number of liars is $2$. because $1$ said $3$ liars $2$ said $4$ liars $3$ said $5$ liars and $4$ said $1$ liars and $5$ said $2$ liars. then if $1$ liar then $4$ and $3$ knights. Whence it follows that $4$ is also a liar and $2$ knight. Well, then the minimum number of liars in our case is $90$.

> **Question**:is it correct answer?

EDIT: I’ll try to explain it. Let's say if there are people in a circle with numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ ..., $181$ then this means that #$1$ says that either #$3$ or #$180$ is a liar, #$2$ says that either #$4$ or #$181$ is a liar and so forth.

Comment: What does _through one person_ mean?

Comment: Do you mean "One of the two people standing next to me is a liar?"  Or do you mean something else?  Also, I can't make any sense of your solution.  Try using shorter, more explicit sentences.

Comment: Is the question exactly the same as in the Olympiad? Please don't interpret yourself because the interpretation may miss an essential detail.

Comment: @saulspatz no, you misunderstood

Comment: So what *do* you mean?  "Through one person there is a liar from me," isn't English.

Comment: @Pieter21 this question was in one of the Russian olympiads I translated it with the help of a google translator

Comment: I’ll try to explain it. Let's say if there are people in a circle with numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$ ..., $181$ then this means that 1 said that 3 liar n said $n+2$ liar and so on but you have to take into account that they stand in a circle then when the turn reaches $180$ people he will say that $1$ liar. something like that

Comment: My question is, if there is  a circle of 5 people, 1 can claim that either 4 is a liar, or 3 is a liar. If 1 says 3 is a liar, does 3 have to say 5 is a liar or can 3 say that 1 is a liar?

Comment: @art1488: Can you post a link to the original problem in Russian?

Comment: Found out this to be the question asked in the olympiad: "Ten people are sitting around a round table. Some of them are knights who always tell the truth, and some of them are knaves who always lie. Two people said, “Both neighbors of mine are knaves.” The other eight people said, “Both neighbors of mine are knights.” How many knights might be sitting around the round table?"

Comment: “Both neighbors of mine are liars.” or "the person next to both my neighbours are liars?"

Comment: "the persons next to both my neighbours are liars"

Comment: Or: there is a liar two places away?!

Comment: @Pieter21 my neighbor’s neighbor is a liar

Comment: @art1488, it is more subtle, at least one of my two neighbor's neighbors is a liar.

Comment: @AndrewChin, by now, 'through one' has been clarified as the second person next to me in either direction in the circle. Could you reopen the question, since I think it is a nice problem?

Comment: @saulspatz, same as for Andrew, by now, 'through one' has been clarified as the second person next to me in either direction in the circle. Could you reopen the question, since I think it is a nice problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, everyone in the circle says 2 persons away (in any direction) there is a liar.

The minimal pattern that matches is $KxLyK$ - the $L$ lies because there isn't one, and the $K$'s both tell the truth.

We can interleave two of those patterns and repeat pattern $KKLLKK$ 30 times.

Then you have to close the circle with a $L$. On both sides, the second item is a $K$, which repeats the pattern.

The solution therefor: $61$

Comment: This does not work.  If I do $KKLLKKKKLLKK$ there are two pairs of $K$s in the middle where one calls the other a liar.

Comment: In a circle you can look both ways (in my interpretation of the problem), and you have to look 2 places away. There needs to be only one liar.

Comment: You are reading the problem differently from me.  I agree that OP has not been very clear.

Comment: @Pieter21 yes you understood the task correctly

Comment: @RossMillikan, I can read around 7 languages, so the 'through' mis-translation made some sense to me.

Comment: If this is the case, all people can be liars as there would be two liars not one standing two people away from each one.

Comment: @Pieter21 so one person can claim that 2 places next to him, one is a liar, the other is telling the truth?

Comment: @arnav007, in my interpretation it can..

Comment: @Vasya 
ты говоришь по-русски?

Comment: @art1488: Yes, I do

Comment: @Vasya так вот он оригинал этой задачи По кругу стоят $181$ человек, каждый из которых либо рыцарь, либо лжец (лжецы всегда лгут, а рыцари всегда говорят правду). Каждый из стоявших сказал: «Через одного человека от меня есть лжец». Найдите минимальное возможное число лжецов среди этих $181$ человек

Comment: @Pieter21: After reading the problem in Russian, I also see that your interpretation of the problem is correct.

Comment: @Vasya, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Your solution for five does not work.  When you assume $1$ is a liar you find $4$ and $3$ tell the truth.  You did not pursue that to say $3$ says $5$ is a liar and must tell the truth, so $5$ is a liar.  Then $5$ says $2$ is a liar, so $2$ tells the truth.  $2$ says $4$ is a liar, which is a contradiction.  The same thing will happen if you assume $1$ tells the truth.  There is no consistent solution.

It is similar for $181$ or number equivalent to $1 \bmod 4$ in the circle.  If we assume $1$ tells the truth, every fourth person tells the truth up to $181$.  Then $2$ is a liar and so is every fourth person up to $178$.  $180$ tells the truth, saying $1$ is a liar and we have the same contradiction.

Comment: So the problem has no solutions?

Comment: I mean that 1 says both about 180 and about 3 and says that one of the liars each person speaks of two other persons

Comment: That doesn't seem to match your edit, but it doesn't matter.  If $1$ calls $3$ a liar it is the same as if $3$ calls $1$ a liar.  Either way they have to be of opposite kinds.  I only use the fact that person $n$ calls person $n+2 \bmod 181$ a liar, which is enough to reach the contradiction.